# Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\URL" not found

Tags: authentication, middleware, handle, foundation, illuminate

URL does not exist in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth .composer update did not fix it.

> error in App  \  Http  \  Middleware  \  RedirectIfAuthenticated

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated

{

```
/**

 * Handle an incoming request.

 *

 * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next

 */

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string ...$guards): Response

{

    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;



    foreach ($guards as $guard) {

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);

        }

    }



    return $next($request);

}
```

}